# missing previous state with using function inside provider - nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have a provider like this:

```
import {createContext, useContext, useState} from 'react'

// Create Context object.
const CartContext = createContext({
   deliveryPersion:'own',//or other
   coupon:{},
   updateCoupon: (obj) => {},
   updateDeliveryPersion: (type) => {},
})



// Export Provider.
export function CartProvider(props) {

   const updateCoupon = (_coupon) => {
      setState({...state,coupon: _coupon})
   }


  const updateDeliveryPersion = (type) => {
     setState({...state,deliveryPersion: type})
   }



   const initState = {
      deliveryPersion:'own',
      coupon:{},
      updateCoupon:updateCoupon,
      updateDeliveryPersion:updateDeliveryPersion
   }

   const [state, setState] = useState(initState)
    
    return (
       <CartContext.Provider value={state}>
        {props.children}
       </CartContext.Provider>
    )
}

// Export useContext Hook.
export function useCartContext() {
    return useContext(CartContext);
}
```

My senario:
I have two components. `component1` and `component1`.

inside `component1` I updated the `deliveryPersion` variable like this:

```
...
cartContext.updateDeliveryPersion('other')
```

inside `component2` I updated `coupon` object:

```
const data = {/**/}
cartContext.updateCoupon(data)
```

at this here `deliveryPersion` changed to default value.(`own` value).
in other word, I missing current value with using update function.

where is my problem?

for example first component:

```
const cartContext =  useCartContext()
cartContext.updateDeliveryPersion(type)
```

Comment: Can you show more of the two components you're working with?

Comment: @DaveVanFleet updated my question.

Comment: Thanks! Maybe a little more? For example how are you accessing `coupon` and `deliveryPerson`? Is the problem that you're trying to update `deliveryPerson` in component1, then trying to access the new value in component2, but are seeing the old data?

Comment: Change the `setState` function calls to the following format: `setState((state) => {...state, coupon: _coupon})`. This ensures the state you're accessing is always the current one.